# Can you use EV SSL on Apache without a private key?

Tags: ssl, apache2

Can you use EV SSL on Apache without a private key?

I'm guessing this question is a no brainer, I've never heard of having a site on Apache covered by SSL without having a private key, but I'm no security guru so I thought I'd ask here so I can be sure.

The reason I ask is that we have just jumped through a million hoops to get our EV SSL certificate, and they've sent through the .crt file along with all the parent .crt files to construct our .pem file, but there's no .key attachment to any email, and none of the files have the telltale comment `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: You can't use _any_ type of certificate for server authentication without the appropriate private key.  There must have been a private key generated at one point otherwise there will not be a matching public key in the certificate request.  The location of that private key, depends on the process you used to generate the request.

Comment: Yeah, as I thought. I'll get the boss to chase up the issuer and get they key from them. So much for the out of hours deployment :/

Comment: You should really study how certificates work, you really need that information in your work. The issuer doesn't have the private key, since that would be insecure. It is your organization that has the private key, which is used to generate the certificate request, which is then sent to the issuer.

Comment: Thanks Tero, this is why I asked. I've set up SSL twice in the past, many years ago. I'll ask the boss for the key, hopefully he still has it somewhere.

Comment: Yep, found the key on the records from a while ago, when we first applied for the certificates. It's in and working fine now, thanks for the help @TeroKilkanen and garethTheRed, much appreciated :)